# "we met at a party" vs. "we didn't meet at a party"

Tags: grammar

Would you be able to explain to me why do they use ***met*** in the first sentence, and ***meet*** in the second? I thought there is a **past tense** in common:

> 1. We met at a party
> 2. We didn't meet at a party

Comment: 'met' is just a short way of saying 'did meet'. Same as "We ate food" vs "We didn't eat food" here [ate = did eat]

Answer (score 4):

To make the sentence negative, we added the helping verb "**do**", as there is no negative form of "**meet**".

> helping verb (**do**) + infinitive (to **meet**)

Now, converting the sentence to past, we'll change the verb from present to past, and **do** will be changed to the past tense, hence **meet** will stay in its original present form.

You can see that "**did not meet**" is correct because the correct past tense is "did meet".

> - We didn't meet at a party.
> - We did not meet at a party.
> - We did meet at a party.
> - *We did not <s>met</s> at a party.*  (Not correct)
> - We met at a party.
> - *<s>We met not at a party.</s>*  (Not standard English)